# How can I automatically resize up images to fit into all of my registered image sizes

Tags: php, images

I need Wordpress to create versions of each image in ALL of the registered image size, even if the registered image size is larger than the uploaded file.

For example, if I have the following registered image sizes:

- large: 1024x1024
- medium: 800x600
- my-custom: 645x200

and I upload a an image of the dimensions 200x200, I need the system to scale the image up and crop it into all of the image sizes.

How would I go about doing this? Or is there a plugin somewhere that could do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is called "upscaling images". Wordpress does not do that by default (with reasons). 
2 solutions:

1. no physical upscaling: display your images via CSS (and not as IMG
   html tags), using `background-size: cover;`
2. a plugin that upscale images. Here is [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-upscale/) (untested).

Comment: You are the man. Sometimes the terminology is half the battle. :D